# Thieves Planet?

Tags: story-identification

Government agent sent on a mission to a planet of "thieves". He soon discovers that he is being outwitted at every turn by its inhabitants. He is captured, interrogated, turned by a local female gang leader.

Comment: Is this a novel, a short story, or a film? When did you see/read this and where? Please do read our [guidelines for story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question).